# Django Admin (1.11.14) showing 404 error after login (www.mysite/admin/login/?next=/admin/)

Tags: django, postgresql, django-admin, passenger

I'm using a2hosing passenger_wsgi.py
My django version is 1.11.14 , the frontend looks good even I can see the django admin login page. But when I try to login as superuser ( of course with valid credentials ) its taking me to `www.mysite/admin/login/?next=/admin/`  , with 404 error

The error msg :

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    mysite/admin/login/?next=/admin/
Raised by:  django.contrib.admin.sites.login
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^admin/
The current path, login/,thing, match any of these.
```

Last thing , when test django-admin check from console (ssh) , i'm also getting :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'
```

**passenger_wsgi.py :**

```
import sys, os
INTERP = "/home/newcoll1/virtualenv/public__html_mainsite/3.6/bin/python"
#INTERP is present twice so that the new python interpreter
#knows the actual executable path 
if sys.executable != INTERP: os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)

cwd = os.getcwd()
sys.path.append(cwd)
sys.path.append(cwd + '/mysite')  #You must add your project here

sys.path.insert(0,cwd+'/virtualenv/public__html_mainsite/3.6/bin')
sys.path.insert(0,cwd+'/virtualenv/public__html_mainsite/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages')

# os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**settings.py**

```
import os



# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '*****'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*****','*****']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mainsite',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'newcollectiblefineart.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'newcollectiblefineart.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

# DATABASES = {
#     'default': {
#         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#         'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
#     }
# }

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': '*****',
        'USER': '*****',
        'PASSWORD': '*****',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '*****'    

    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/newcoll1/public_html/mainsite/newcollectiblefineart/static/'

STATIC_URL = '/mainsite/newcollectiblefineart/static/'
```

**urls.py :**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include 
from django.contrib import admin



urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

]
```

Comment: `www.mysite/admin/login/?next=/admin/` this doesn't looks like a valid url, what url are you hitting in the browser to open your admin panel?

Comment: www.mysite.com/admin

but after login ,it is redirecting to /admin/login/?next=/admin/

Comment: @user2906838 any idea ?

Comment: It is redirecting to the malformed url. Without seeing some of your codes, it's impossible to just to guess.

Comment: @user2906838 ...  should i provide settings.py and urls.py , please let me know ,

Comment: Ya, please share them.

Comment: urls.py .......

Comment: from django.conf.urls import url, include 
from django.contrib import admin



urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    
]

Comment: settings.py ............

Comment: You should edit your question and add these things there, not in the comment. That would be easy.

Comment: @user2906838 .... i have shared , passgenger_wsgi.py , settings.py and urls.py

Comment: Can you please try testing your app with `python manage.py runserver` instead of wsgi, just to validate.

Comment: @user2906838 : did that with 
1)python manage.py runserver 
2)and python manage.py runserver mysite:8000
3) deleting passenger_wsgi and run 1) and 2) 
but site not running nd there is no error showing on putty terminal.

Comment: If you're not able to run your project using `manage.py` then, it's unlikely it will run through any other way. Can't you access  `/admin' page? Where are you running this, in putty terminal? If you're trying to run in in remote server through putty, then try to access the website using the serverip:port, and see.

Comment: As i mentioned earlier i'm using passenger_wsgi (a2hosting), I can see the Django Welcome Page, and also the Django Admin Login page , but whenever m going to login with valid username and password (superuser) , its taking me to the www.mysite/admin/login/?next=/admin/) , I have also noticed if i use invalid login credentials , there is no validation showing as well , rather taking to 404 page.

Comment: Please turn on your debug mode, and also please check the route to the login page in your login html. It shouldn't take you to the malformed url, strange that is.

Comment: in settings.py , DEBUG = True
route is also default which django provides ,
u can check my urls.py
m not using any custom login page, M using default django admin login.

Comment: Yes, I meant to say, when you load the login page, inspect the login form in the browser and check where it's pointing but I guess the route must be relative.

Comment: <form action="/admin/login/?next=/admin/" method="post" id="login-form"><input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="oqQoyf6aLWiGuziI8Q2jsqwgs96y4nSmJs0ykcuEO4yKFRANfqUAKK4E9xwNuGdU">

Comment: @user2906838 ... any luck?

Comment: I  wish I could debug that project myself, haha. But anyway `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'` , do you still get this while doing `django-admin check  admin mysite`? It almost looks like I can't do anything, since I can't produce the error. But the only strange thing is the `.com` is missing in that request url, otherwise it should have worked.

Comment: while doing that ... its showing the error ,

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting USE_I18N, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.